Is this the correct notation for equivalence relation for directed limit for the directed system of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from: A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then, the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2: The direct sum of the family of the subgroup is defined as
$$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i=\{f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)\neq 1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i\}$$
with the restricted operation.
Definition 3:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 4:  A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

Definition 5:  A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_iG_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,
if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their iimages in $G_k$.
Questions:
In continuation of this post, post, and post. I would like to ask
In Definition 5 2., the equivalence relation $\sim$ is defined as "for $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$, $x_i\sim x_j$ if and only if $G_i\xrightarrow{\phi_{ik}(x_i)}G_k=G_j\xrightarrow{\phi_{jk}(x_j)}G_k$"?  I just want to make sure that I am reading and understanding the notations correctly.
Thank you in advance

Your definition of the sum has an extra negation; you want elements of the product that are the identity in all but finitely many coordinates.

@SammyBlack sorry I just saw this now.  Do you mean the $\oplus$ sum "$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i={f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)\neq 1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i}$
with the restricted operation", should read as:  "$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i={f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)=1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i}$
with the restricted operation" instead?  The $\neq$ sign is the extra negation sign you were referring to?

Yes, the way it's written, your sum isn't a group.

I second Sammy's comments. This is unusually written and I'm not sure what is going on with your $\bigoplus G_i$. Look up "colimits in groups" "arbitrary free product" etc.. Also $f(i)=1_G$ for all but finitely many $i$ is the appropriate condition - at least if you want your definition of $\bigoplus_i G_i$ to agree with the one for Abelian groups (where more usually one would write $0$ than $1$)

@FShrike what I want to know is in Definition 7, when it says:  "$x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$", is that equivalent to in phrasing:  "for $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$, $x_i\sim x_j$ if and only if $G_i\xrightarrow{\phi_{ik}(x_i)}G_k=G_j\xrightarrow{\phi_{jk}(x_j)}G_k$"?

No. $x_i,x_j$ are just elements of the groups $G_i,G_j$. It's like in the question of yours that I originally answered, you're misusing the definition of a product via functions $I\to\bigcup_iG_i$. Also it's if and only if there exists a $k$ (greater than $i$ and $j$) such that $\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$. This is just an application of a function to an element of its domain, an equation of elements in $G_k$.

If you look at general colimits of (Abelian) groups or sets or whatever you'll see it's a bit more complicated. I should stress that this poset structure makes life easier

@FShrike in the definition of equivalence relation $\sim$, I treat both $\phi_{ik}(x_i),\phi_{jk}(x_j)$ as elements belonging to $G_k$?

@Seth You don't just treat them like that, they are that! Yes, they are both elements of $G_k$
